# iOS 9 Presenting Popover takes full screen

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, ios9

I am trying to present a PopOver view controller, specifically to show a small filters screen next to a TextField. However it is showing as a full-screen view controller. filters_button is the one that should trigger the pop-over. Any ideas why this is showing full screen as if it were a normal ViewController?

```
func showFilters(){
    let tableViewController = UITableViewController()
    tableViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
    tableViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(20, 20)

    presentViewController(tableViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    let popoverPresentationController = tableViewController.popoverPresentationController
    popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = filters_button
    popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, filters_button.frame.size.width, filters_button.frame.size.height)
}

func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return .None
}
```

Note: At the top of my class I declare that it conforms the "UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate" protocol

Comment: @Lu_ Apple has deprecated the action sheet in iOS 8.3

Comment: Perhaps try changing the line to `popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view` and `popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = filters_button.frame`

Comment: I changed those two and same result, popOver shows in the entire screen...

Comment: Would it maybe work to move the presentViewController line to the end of the method, after the popoverPresentationController lines?

Comment: No... I tried it just to make sure but that doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fixed**:
Given that for the PopOver to work on iPhone devices, you need to set the delegate of popoverPresentationController before the viewController is presented, that way the method below gets called by the delegate. So add

```
    popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
```

below

```
    popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = filters_button.frame
```

and move

```
    self.presentViewController(filtersVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

to the end of the function.

Comment: what method gets called by the delegate?

Comment: @SpaceDog `adaptivePresentationStyle` only takes effect if the delegate has been set.

Answer (score 2):

You should add the following

```
func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController, traitCollection: UITraitCollection) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return .none
}
```